# Unable to add .NET class libraries to Store apps project

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am developing a Windows Store app to capture the live feed from webcam and show it in a CaptureElement control using MediaCapture API. However I am not able to add my existing project class libraries which are developed using .NET framework v4.5. I get the error:
"The project targets .NET core while the file reference targets .NET framework. This is not a supported scenario".
On searching in forums about it I found on converting to portable class libraries I will be able to add it. So I ended up converting my dll to PCL but found lot of base class libraries are not supported in PCL like System.Data.dll is not present. Also, the existing project references in that PCL should also be converted to PCL. So this is like an endless loop.
Is there a workaround? Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected and correct. Windows Store apps don't use the full .Net Framework. They use .Net classes only from the [.Net Framework for Windows Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br230232.aspx) apps subset (see [.NET for Windows Store apps overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br230232.aspx)).

You will need to refactor your class libraries to depend on .Net namespaces which are available to Windows Store apps. Other functionality (e.g. file and network access) is available via the Windows Runtime or third party libraries.

There isn't a direct analogue for System.Data. Depending on what in System.Data you are using you may be able to connect to a remote server via a web service or you might look into a local database such as SQLite.

So long as the base functionality is available, you may be able to shim differences by writing classes or attached methods which match the interfaces your app currently uses but implement the behaviour via supported means. I discuss some strategies for doing so in my blog entry [Porting tips: bridging differences in the .Net Framework for Windows Runtime apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2015/01/22/porting-tips-shaving-the-differences-in-the-net-framework-for-windows-runtime-apps.aspx)